# One-to-one map with Java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Having a little trouble using the Stream API to get a one to one mapping. Basically, say you've got a class.

```
public class Item {
    private final String uuid;

    private Item(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    /**
    * @return universally unique identifier
    */
    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }
}
```

I'd like a `Map<String, Item>` for easy look up. But given a `Stream<Item>` there doesn't seem a simple way to arrive at that `Map<String, Item>`.

Obviously, `Map<String, List<Item>>` ain't no thing:

```
public static Map<String, List<Item>> streamToOneToMany(Stream<Item> itemStream) {
    return itemStream.collect(groupingBy(Item::getUuid));
}
```

That's the safer more general case, but we *do* know in this situation that there will only ever be one-to-one. I can't find anything that compiles though -- I've specifically been trying to muck with the `downstream` parameter to `Collectors.groupingBy`. Something like:

```
// DOESN'T COMPILE
public static Map<String, Item> streamToOneToOne(Stream<Item> itemStream) {
    return itemStream.collect(groupingBy(Item::getUuid, Function.identity()));
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [`Collectors#toMap(Function, Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-), generating the key from each `Item`'s `uuid` and the `Item` as the value itself.

```
public static Map<String, Item> streamToOneToOne(Stream<Item> itemStream) {
    return itemStream.collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getUuid, Function.identity()));
}
```

Note from the javadoc

> If the mapped keys contains duplicates (according to
>   `Object.equals(Object)`), an `IllegalStateException`is thrown when the
>   collection operation is performed. If the mapped keys may have
>   duplicates, use `toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator)` instead.

Comment: It worth adding that an exception will be thrown if repeating key occurs.

Answer (score 2):

`groupingBy()` collects items (plural, as a `List`) by a key.

You want `toMap()`:

```
public static Map<String, Item> streamToOneToOne(Stream<Item> itemStream) {
    return itemStream.collect(toMap(Item::getUuid, Function.identity()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
itemStream.stream().collect(toMap(Item::getUuid,Functions.identity());
```