# Create a map out of Object Java8

Tags: lambda, java-8

I have a class:

```
Class Sample {
  String first;
  String second;
}
```

I want to create a map like:

```
first->second
```

What will be the lambda expression to achieve this.

Comment: You need to use `Collectors.toMap`, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31640588/1743880

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Sample s = new Sample("first", "second");
Map<String, String> m = 
    Stream.of(s)
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Sample::getFirst, Sample::getSecond));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use plain old [`Collections.singletonMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonMap-K-V-):

```
Sample s = new Sample("first", "second");
Map<String, String> m = Collections.singletonMap(s.getFirst(), s.getSecond());
```